# DocuSign: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: docusignapi

I get the url back from the RecipientView which I then update the window.location.href with.

When I am directed to the DocUSign contract window, I am unable to sign the contract or see my text tab.

I get the below error. What is the best way to resolve this?

```
demo.docusign.net/:1 Access to script at 'https://a.docusign.com/ds_arya_wrapper.min.js?f=1' from origin 'https://demo.docusign.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
demo.docusign.net/:384 
 GET https://a.docusign.com/ds_arya_wrapper.min.js?f=1 net::ERR_FAILED
```

[image]

Below you can only see one app listed in the CORS allowed list and the particular app I am working with is not there?

[image]

If I go to edit the setting of my particular app, I can add a URL to the CORS but it has to be https whereas I am currently on http:localhost as I am building the app.

[image]

Comment: Is your application running in a browser? Or on the server?

Comment: I'm using Next.js 13. So the Next.js server calls the DocuSign ApI. Then the front-end of Next.js calls my backend Next.js API.

Comment: See my updated answer. If you have further questions, please post them as new questions on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is *not* a bulletin board or forum; the idea is that each question is specific and stand-alone. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

### Next.js is not using CORS to DocuSign

In your comment you say:

> the Next.js server calls the DocuSign ApI. Then the front-end of Next.js calls my backend Next.js API

In this case, your Next.js app is ***not*** using CORS. The front-end is calling the back-end, then the back-end (the server) is calling DocuSign. This is a standard web app configuration. It works great and it is **not** using CORS.

### If you use CORS for a different app

Use the Apps and Keys page to add the origin `http://localhost` to your client ID (integration key) configuration. Using http://localhost is only supported on the developer platform [demo.docusign.net](https://demo.docusign.net).

All other other CORS origins must use https.

On the DocuSign production system, you must use https. (You can use https://localhost, but not with a self-signed server cert.)

**Then, on the CORS section of the settings tool**
Check that you're allowing CORS by default

**Then run your application** After it makes a **successful** CORS call, you'll see `http://localhost` as an origin for your application listed on the `CORS page`

Comment: https://admindemo.docusign.com/apps-and-keys/b2631833-dfa9-4270-b99b-3b721121234abc

When I go to the above domain and got to this section "List of origin URLs where CORS will be allowed. Maximum of 20 origins allowed." I get the error  "The origin must be a valid https URL (example: https://www.docusign.com)". Is there a setting I need to change to allow cors?

Comment: CORS require https, but to allow CORS you have to also do other things. I suggest you read the documentation on https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/single-page-applications-cors/ to learn more about CORS

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot sign this envelope is because you didn't provide any tags/tabs/signing elements.

The CORS error you see is an internal DocuSign error which you can ignore.

You did not use CORS to build your integration because you clearly was able to make API calls, your issue is not related to CORS but to how you created this envelope.